# How to access Vue Instance from within an argument function?

Tags: vue.js

So based off [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178621/how-to-correctly-use-vue-js-watch-with-lodash-debounce/45178679#45178679) I implemented this snippet:

```
methods: {
    checkSearchString: _.debounce( string => {
         console.log("watcher firing for search!");
         console.log(this.searchInput);
        this.$emit("search", this.searchInput);
    }, 2000)
},
watch: {
    searchInput : "checkSearchString"
}
```

but as comments on the accepted answer pointed out, "this" does not points to the vue instance, so I can't access it. How could I access the vue instance from within the function? or how could I solve this better?

the main goal here is to use _.debounce and a watcher to fire the search when the user  stops typing, and achieve that in a clean way.

Edit: Thanks for pointing the use of the arrow function as the problem of context here, the users on the other thread did point to this being the problem but I didn't get why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuex: \_this.$store is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799617/vuex-this-store-is-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you using arrow function which losing context.
do it with normal anonymous function

```
watch: {
    searchInput : "checkSearchString"
}

methods: {
    checkSearchString: _.debounce( function(value) {
         console.log("watcher firing for search!");
         console.log(value);
        this.$emit("search", value);
    }, 2000)
},
```